# SSRS Report Fails, How do you determine root cause?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have a report that essentially is a purchase order.  It contains multiple tablixs and about 4-5 shared datasets.  For some reason when I attempt to load a PO for specific purchase orders the report goes into a loop and just sits there while the report server spirals up in terms of memory and CPU usage.

When I break out one tablix from the report (it happens to have a grouping in it) the report will run fine and if I place that same tablix in a report all it's own it works fine as well.

Anyone have an idea why this behavior is happening and more importantly what's the best way to troubleshoot these stupid reports?  I have checked everything from the data source to physically rebuilding the entire report and myself and a colleague are totally out of ideas.

Thanks for whatever you can offer!

Brent

Comment: Do you have any expressions executing? Any custom code? Sounds suspiciously like an recursive/infinite loop problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this problem was somehow related to the HTML rendering aspect through our web portal.  If you run the report in other mediums such as an actual .NET forms application it renders fine.  Must be a bug in the HTML generation for this specific report.